# Keyboard focus on first file in Windows explorer?

Tags: windows, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, windows-explorer

When i open windows explorer, I usually navigate it with keyboard most of the time. My biggest annoyance is when I open a folder, and in it I want to open the first folder or file in the list. For this, I have to press the down arrow key, and the up arrow to get the focus on that file/folder. How could I make Explorer, automatically focus on the first file, so once i open the folder, I can just click enter and it opens?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The <kbd>space</kbd> key selects the first folder or file in the list.

Comment: Pressing 'space' is better than 'page up'

Answer (score 4):

I faced the same problem so I created a simple AutoHotKey script to solve this problem

```
~Enter::
    ControlGetText path, ToolbarWindow323
    Sleep 100           
    if WinActive("ahk_class CabinetWClass") {
        ControlGetText new_path, ToolbarWindow323
        if (new_path != path) {
            SendInput {Space}
        }
    }
Return
```

Answer (score 2):

This workarround may be helpful try using ***Enter*** to open a folder then ***PageUp*** to select the first file/folder  the key page up will select the first subfolder on the opened folder

Comment: I think you misunderstood my answer i mean press the key "Enter" to open a folder then press "Page Up" and the first folder/file is selected so it's only two keystrokes instead.

Comment: 10 years later and still helpful.